# CSS border radius not working into UIwebview

Tags: html, css, uiwebview, background-color

on a uiwebview, html rounded button doesn't appear rounded. The background color leak.

They appear ok on regular browser, but square in the webview.

How to solve this?

```
 <button style="color: white; background-color: #ff0000;border-radius:20px; ">39</button>

 <button style="color: white; background-color: #ff0000;border-radius:20px; ">40</button>
```

Result:
Result was ok chrome

Result in ios Webview:

[image]

Comment: I believe the `background-clip` property will stop the leakage of the background color outside the border radius.Try `background-clip: padding-box;`.

Comment: Thanks, but not working.(same leak)
<button style="color: white; background-color: #ff0000;border-radius:20px;background-clip: padding-box; ">34</button>

Comment: Hmmm. Well... try adding these lines `webView.clipsToBounds = true` and `webView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0`

Comment: Forgot to mention ^^ Add these to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For ios you use this style property by making  file of css:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius, 
bottom-right-radius
```

etc. to the correct sub elements.

Comment: Thanks, but not working (same leak)
  <p><span style="font-size: 13pt; font-family: Montserrat-Light;">
 <button style="color: white; background-color: #ff0000;webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10; bottom-right-radius:10; ">38</button>

Comment: why you use button you use html5 tags input it work because in my project it works

Comment: Can you please provide a sample?  (sorry, not html expert) . Thanks!